# Harmonic functions vanishing on the boundary and distance function asymptotics

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ be a $C^2$ domain. Let $u$ be a function such that $u \in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ and $u = \Delta u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Is it true that $$ c \le \frac{u}{[\mathrm{dist}(x, \partial \Omega)]^2} \le C $$
or some other similar estimate holds? Can we obtain similar results if $\Omega$ is less regular?

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}$ $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$ Suppose that $N=2$ and
$\Omega$ is is the unit disk.   Choose 
$$
u= -1+ar^4+br^5\in C^2(\overline{\Omega}).
$$
Then $u=0$ along $\pa \Omega$ implies $a+b=1$.  Next
$$
\Delta u=\frac{1}{r}\pa_r\big(\; r \pa_r u\;\big)= \frac{1}{r}\pa_r(4ar^4+5br^5)=16ar^2+25br^3.
$$
The equality $\Delta u=0$ along $\pa \Omega$ implies $16a+25b=0$. Since $a=1-b$ we deduce
$$ 16-16b+25b=0\implies b=-\frac{16}{9},\;\;a=\frac{25}{9}. $$

Note that
$$\pa_r u=\frac{1}{9}\big(\; 100 r^3-80 r^4\;\big). $$

Along the boundary we have $\pa_ru=\frac{20}{9}$ which implies  that

$$ u(x)\sim \frac{20}{9}\dist\big(x,\Omega\big)\;\;\mbox{near $\pa\Omega$}.
$$

Comment: Is there any way to recover the square under additional assumptions?

Comment: For example, what if we require also $\nabla u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: You also need $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \nu^2}\neq 0$.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Think Taylor expansion in normal direction.

Comment: Think of the special situation in my answer when $\Omega$ is the unit disk in the plane and f$u$ is radially symmetric. Look  at the  Taylor expansion in $r$   near $r=1$, $$u=u(1)+\partial_r(1)(r-1)+\partial^2_ru(1)(r-1)^2/2+O(\;(r-1)^3\;),$$ where $|r-1|={\rm dist}\;(x,\partial \Omega)$, $\partial_r=\partial_\nu$.